# "Rather than do", "rather than doing" or "rather than to do" after "prefer to do something"?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is the most correct and natural.

> I prefer to read books **rather than listening** to them.
>
> I prefer to read books **rather than listen** to them.
>
> I prefer to read books **rather than to listen** them.

If all are natural, than which one is more common?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer:

> Number 1 is "kind of" correct.
>
> Number 2 is grammatically correct.
>
> Number 3 is absolutely false.

Long answer:

it's grammatical to use simple form of the verb or the ing form of the verb after "rather than" -it's ungrammatical to use an infinitive (to+verb) after it.

so with that in mind, number 3 is definitely incorrect and one and two are correct. between one and two I would say number 2 is better because it respects "parallelism"; the two expressions on each side of "than" have the same form (they're both base form), English favors parallelism.

Comment: Not so. Number #3 is in fact *the most "correct" form*. English generally favours ***parallelism***, so ***to listen*** is the preferred verb form because it matches the preceding "counterpoint" ***to read***. It's "acceptable" to delete the predictably repeated second occurrence of infinitive marker ***to***, but that certainly doesn't make it "more correct".